# 'textList' was used before it was defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have imported a textList from a dummy .jsx file and tried to initialised it in a useState function but it gives me the error 'textList' was used before it was defined.

```
const [textList, setTextList] = useState(textList);
```

Error:

```
'textList' was used before it was defined .eslint no-use-before-define
```

Comment: use a different variable name

Comment: Do something like Import textList as defaultTextList is an interesting option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***It is happening because you have already imported textList in that file. So, just renaming the variable name will solve your issue.***

***For example:***

```js
// Rename the variable name textList to anything else
const [tList, setTList] = useState(textList);
```

***Or, if you want to use the variabe as textList then you have to import textList as another name.***

***For example:***

```js
// use this one to import textList as tList
import {textList as tList} from "your-module-name"

// Or use this one
import * as tList from "your-module-name"

// Now use tList inside useState instead of textList 
const [textList, setTextList] = useState(tList);
```